# C - pointer to array: how to copy just the value (not address) of one pointer to another?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If a pointer `pr` points to an array `aa = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`, then we can access the array through the pointer `pr[0]`, `pr[1]`, `pr[2]`,....
How can I shift the array (operated through the pointer) such that I can get`{1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0}`? obviously `pr[i] = pr[i-1]` won't work.

---

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int aa[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int i, m, *pr = aa;
    printf("\n pr[0] = %d, pr[1] = %d, pr[2] = %d, pr[3] = %d", pr[0], pr[1], pr[2], pr[3]);

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        m = *(pr + i);
        pr[i+1] = m;
    }

    printf("\n \n pr[0] = %d, pr[1] = %d, pr[2] = %d, pr[3] = %d \n", pr[0], pr[1], pr[2], pr[3]);
    printf("\n \n aa[0] = %d, aa[1] = %d, aa[2] = %d, aa[3] = %d \n", aa[0], aa[1], aa[2], aa[3]);
    return(1);
}
```

I am writing a C function for R using `.Call`, all the arrays in the C function have to be accessed through this type of the pointers. And I am very confused by the grammar of pointers in C.

Comment: If you want to be able to support this kind of operation I suggest using a linked list. It will give you `O(1)` insertion at the head. As far as I know what you want to do isn't possible, array sizes are mostly fixed in C. You would need to make a new array

Comment: sounds like you might want the function `memmove`.

Comment: ...or implement a circular buffer. No simple magic here.

Comment: Isn't memmove for strings? Does it work for numeric values as well?

Comment: `memmove` is not limited to strings. It works for numeric values. You just need to multiply the number of elements by the size of each element. With strings the size of each element is 1 by definition. But with an array of `int`, you would use `sizeof(int)` to get the size.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why "obviously pr[i] = pr[i-1] won't work"? This should work fine. It just depends on the direction of your loop. You array does not grow but only the content moves.

Comment: @Mitchel0022 the expected output is not larger than the input array. Now growing is requested.

Comment: @harmony Functions for string handling start with `str...`. The `mem...` functions are explicitely not limited to string.

Comment: @Gerhardh you are right but if he used a linked list the operation would be `O(1)` rather than `O(N)`, especially if he had a circular list where he could just move the "start" pointer. For small arrays shifting would be fine

Comment: @Mitchel0022 without knowing the R application and the interface to C it is rather hard to tell if a linked list makes thing better or worse or maybe is not possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to prepend a value, in your example `1`, and remove the last value from the array, in your example a `0`.

If you take a look at what happens you will see the following:

```
position:    0  1  2  3  4  5  6
starting: { a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 }
              \  \  \  \  \  \
final:    { b0 a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 }
```

So you want to do as you proposed shifting each value, but you have to start at the end (or you will overwrite everything with the same value).

```
for(i = 9; i > 0; i--) {
    pr[i]=pr[i-1];
}
pr[0] = NEWVALUE;
```

Comment: The person in the OP could also additionally redesign how they store the data, by reversing how they add to the list. In other words, instead of appending 1 to the front of the array, they could append it to the end so the data can read as `5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0`, although whether that's feasible or worth their time is another matter.

Comment: Smart, however there is little context so if OP has a 'bigger problem' than this very specific one he should have asked a different question.